# Hide/Remove custom Post Type options in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hide/Remove custom Post Type options in Wordpress

Comment: if you link me to your theme, I will check it out for ya.. since Yii tutorials are getting on my nerves, I don't mind stepping out to help ya figure this out.

Comment: I think I have this theme, what section are you trying to remove? can you post a snapshot?

Comment: does look like meta to me, check db or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking i think its to remove what we call "Meta Box" inside the wordpress

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

look inside you theme files for "add_meta_box" method the are related with the post_type you trying to change.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes

make a find inside you theme folder for this "adding_custom_meta_boxes"

this method its gonna be followed by the name of the custom type you're trying to change.

> adding_custom_meta_boxes( $post_type

Hope that help :)

Comment: I think you beat me to it.